# How to test whether a Django FileField is blank?

Tags: django

What is the right way to test whether a Django [FileField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) is blank, i.e., when no file has been uploaded?

It looks like the `name` attribute is `u''` when the field is blank, but I don't know whether that is reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I ran in a similar problem and found a possible solution (surely not the best).
I'm currently checking if the the cleaned data inside the file field is an instance of the class TemporaryUploadedFile (django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile):

** your code here**

from django.core.files.uploadedfile import TemporaryUploadedFile

** your code here**

if isinstance(form_instance.cleaned_data['my_file'], TemporaryUploadedFile):
    # do stuff

I hope this is going to help.

Cheers!
David

Answer (score -2):

This is one from [python idioms](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#testing-for-truth-values), always test it in simplest way possible:

```
if some_object.file:
    # File exists!
    # This of course does not guarantees that file exists on disk, or that it is 
    # readable.
else:
    # No file.
```